# SocketException and IOException when attempting to store an HTML file as a string

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I've tried a few methods at this point to pull this website and stuff it into a variable to later be parsed, and all of them have thrown the same errors:

IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

So far I've tried WebClient.DownloadString() in the .Net lib, something similar in the .Net.Http lib, as well as the HtmlDocument.Load() from the HtmlAgilityPack lib all with the same result. In the .Net lib I've tried the commonly suggested solution of disabling keepalive, and am just assuming at this point that there is some setting on my computer causing this.

Any ideas? And thanks in advance for reading. =)

Here is my current code:

```
string tcgpSite;
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    tcgpSite = wc.DownloadString("http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic?newSearch=true");

Console.WriteLine(tcgpSite);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a probably with the way your using statement is set up in your actual code.

The following works for me:

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient() 
string tcgpSite = wc.DownloadString("http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic?newSearch=true");
```

As does the code you posted.

Otherwise, you may have some kind of fire wall or other network issue closing your connection. The error seems to indicate the same.

> SocketException: An established connection was **aborted by the software in your host machine**.

Try temporarily disabling any firewall or anti virus your machine might be running.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback here!

Ya, I had another friend test it as well and it worked when they ran it in Unity as well so I'm assuming it's something on my end... That being said I don't use AV software and it persists when I disable windows firewall so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are using a proxy? Perhaps windows defender?

Comment: Not using a proxy and disabled Windows Defender permanently via group policy. >.<